# EMR on EKS - Create a job execution role

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-eks

How to create an IAM role to run workloads on Amazon EMR on EKS?
The official documentation remains very vague on this point in particular

Answer (score 0):

This is multistep process. We have EKS cluster on which we run EMR jobs. So we need to setup IAM + EKS role mapping configurations. AWS Documentation is detailed which creates confusion sometimes.

Following are high level steps which might help you to refer AWS documentation again and understand.

Note: These steps assumes you already have created EKS.

1. Create Namespace to run your spark jobs.
2. Create RBAC Role and Role binding for your cluster configuration. (This is EKS level role based access mechanism.)
3. Edit aws-auth to update roleARN for AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEMRContainers. (EKS Authorisation)
4. Create EMR virtual cluster and assigned it to EKS namespace created above.
5. Create trust policy to access EKS cluster for EMR containers.
6. Create Job execution role and associate above policy to it.
7. Submit your emr on eks job.